# What if an input doesn't have an output is it still a function?

Tags: functions

My definition of a function is each input has exactly one output. Based off this it wouldn't be considered a function even if all other inputs are mapped to one outputs. But I'm just double checking in case there's something I've overlooked

Thanks

Comment: I don‘t understand your question. Are you asking whether 0<1 is a function?

Comment: "0 < 1 so it wouldn't be considered a function …" What is *it* here?

Comment: A function is a rule that assigns to every valid input one and only one output. "$0\lt 1$" does not mean anything in this context, so it is unclear what you are going on about.

Comment: An input not having an output is 0 outputs which is not exactly 1 since 0 is less than 1

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is correct. (Apparently, though, people seem to expect you to present your argument as if you were already "mathematically sophisticated".)

Comment: @DavidMitra Well, I just don’t see what they’re saying. The current post seems to be saying, a many-to-one mapping is not a function. But a many-to-one mapping *is* a function. What “it” is is very unclear

Comment: While it would not be a function, it would be a [partial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function)

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is correct. If, for instance, $f$ associates to the number $1$ the number $1$, associates to the number $2$ the number $-3/5$, and associates to the number $3$ both the numbers $7$ and $\pi$, then $f$ is *not* a function.

Comment: You might wonder, then, what kind of mathematical object $f$ *is*, if it is not a function. The answer is that $f$ is a *relation*, which you can read more about [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(mathematics)#Definition). Formally, a relation is a set of ordered pairs, and a function is a set of ordered pairs such that if $(a,b)\in f$ and $(a,c)\in f$, then $b=c$.

Comment: Well, technically speaking, if an value doesn't map to an output then that value is no way an "input", is it?  A function needs to have a *Domain* which is a set of all "input values" and every element in it's domain must be mapped.  But there is no restriction on what that set is.  If we have the function $f(x)=\frac {x^2 + 2x + 1}{x-5}$ that can not input of $x=5$.  But that is okay.  The domain is $\{$all real numbers except $5\}$  and it is a perfectly good function.  Every "input" is mapped and $5$ simply is *not* an input.

Answer (score 1):

Not all texts are consistent but a function *must* have a designated domain.  The designated Domain can be any set and every element of the domain must be mapped.  So if you *tried* to make a function $f:\{red,green, yellow, blue\} \to \mathbb N$ where $f(red) = 1; f(green)= 27; f(blue)=5$ but you didn't map "yellow" to anything that is not a properly defined function because not everything in your domain is mapped.

But if so we just fix it by defining the domain to be $\{red, green, blue\}$ and leave the yellow out of the domain.

You might be wondering if $f(x) = \frac {\sqrt{x-3}}{x-5}$ is a function because $f(5)$ and $f(2)$ and $f(x)$ for all $x < 3$ are undefined.

Well it is a perfectly *fine* function *if* we define the domain properly.  The domain can not include $5$ nor can it include any of $(-\infty, 3)$.  But the domain can be any subset of $[3,5)\cup (5, \infty)$.